# Automatically select other language keyboards - iphone

Tags: xcode, keyboard

Is is possible to select the keyboard language programmatically? Like if user focuses in arabic name field arabic keyboard language is selected and if user enters spanish name field spanish keyboard is selected and if user start typing name in english field automatically select the english language keyboard?

Also can we check the current language of keyboard of user?

Many Thanks,
Naveed Butt

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, this is not possible using the current API.